# Прокси паралельно с основным потоком curl

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Не могу понять как правильно организовать парсинг с использованием прокси, так, что бы запросы с прокси и без него шли паралельно и новые отправлялись не ожидая ответа уже отправленных ? Сейчас я делаю так : разделяю массив ссылок на отдельные массивы   по 15 ссылок с помощью `array_chunk` после чего использую `curl_multi_exec` что бы отправить запрос по ним. Если я разделю общий массив не на 15 а на 20 `URL's` и добавлю половине из них прокси, вторую оставлю как есть :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
```

То общая скорость работы снизится, как я понимаю, потому что ответы от прокси приходят медленнее и это время ничего не отправляется.

Вопрос - как отправляя запросы через прокси, не дожидаться ответов и продолжать слать запросы ? Если есть библиотека реализующая подобное то посоветуйте, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

PS - При запросе разных ресурсов одного сайта, например -

> http://site.com/search.php?id=12345;
>
> http://site.com/search.php?id=12346;

можно ли использовать одно подключение ? Прочитал что открытие соединения требует много времени и лучше использовать одно.

Comment: Имхо, не использовать `curl_multi_exec` и прочую "мультипоточность". Написать скрипт: 1 вызов - 1 ссылка. И сделать очереди через какой-нибудь rabbitmq + "мастер скрипт". Я бы делал именно так.

Comment: @TotalPusher В rabbitmq проще работать с проксями ?

Comment: Нет, он не для проксей. Это просто способ сделать многопоточную обработку. Он просто запускает скрипты. 1 скрипт - 1 запрос. Наваливаем в очередь ссылки, кролик раскидывает.

Comment: @TotalPusher может стоит посмотреть в его тсорону, но с трудом верится что такая технология не потдерживает работу через прокси сервера.

Comment: @TotalPusher зачем усложнять, когда можно запустить PHP-скрипт с одним запросом из bash окончив команду на & и сделать это в bash цикле.

Comment: @Piterden, поясняю почему `php ... &` делать не стоит: если будет over9000 ссылок, сервер нагнется. Или наш, или тот, кого парсим. `такая технология не потдерживает работу через прокси сервера` - какая? вы про брокер? он не для этого

Comment: Да не стоит парсить на PHP. Он изначально не для этого.

Comment: @TotalPusher `Или наш, или тот, кого парсим`  - почему? разве есть разница как именно отправлять запросы?

Comment: @Сергей. Как именно отправлять запросы разницы нет. Особые извращенцы вообще используют `telnet` или `netcat`. Запрос - обычный текст, переданный тем или иным способом. Я говорю про то, что вам наверняка стоит не гнать в один и тот же момент 9000 запросов на сервер, а делать это порциями. Отправили 50, это очередь. Через секунду осталось 40 работающих, а 10 отработали. Отдельным мастер-скриптом подлили в очередь еще 10 новых запросов.

Comment: Сейчас попробую сделать примерчик, чтобы вы понимали о чем речь. Самому стало интересно.

Comment: Не важно сколько будет задач для RabbitMQ/Gearman/etc, главное чтобы они в памяти разместились без проблем, при нужде можно в БД определить. Затем создать рабочие потоки и пусть менеджер выделяет им задачи. (http://gearman.org/examples/multi-query/)

Comment: @TotalPusher 9000 запросов это уже Ddos какой-то. Думаю в моем случае можно просто запустить кроном или мастер скриптом несколько раз один исполняемый скрипт с разными параметрами.